# How to add keys to php array?

Tags: php

```
$c=array("a"=>"blue","b"=>"green");
array_push($c,$c["d"]="red");
print_r($c);
```

this code adding the key in to an array. But it also adding the indexed key to same key/value pair..how to avoid this indexed key?
output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => blue
    [b] => green
    [d] => red
    [0] => red
)
```

Comment: array_push doesn't make any sense on associative arrays, only indexed arrays.

Comment: wondering why the question is downvoted! it's clear and shows a try with code

Answer (score 7):

Just add another key value like this

```
$c=array("a"=>"blue","b"=>"green");
$c["d"]="red";
print_r($c);
```

Out put is

```
Array ( [a] => blue [b] => green [d] => red )
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `array_push()` here it's not necessary. 
Just add new key with value.

```
$c= array("a"=>"blue","b"=>"green");
$c['d'] = 'red';
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add the new key.

```
$c["y"] = "yellow";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add more elements by this way:

```
$array = array("a"=>"blue","b"=>"green");
$array['c'] = 'red';
```

Comment: its working..thank u..how can we do same thing using array_push() ?

Comment: @vaishu you can't

Comment: @vaishu You can't, `array_push` is for non-indexed arrays (and should be used to add multiple values, for single values it's better to use it in this way)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to simply use `$c['d'] = 'red';` ?

Answer (score 2):

Do it like by,

```
$c=array("a"=>"blue","b"=>"green");
$c["d"]="red";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($c);
```

and Output like,

```
Array
(
    [a] => blue
    [b] => green
    [d] => red
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Push the new key-value pair into the array like so:

```
$c["d"] = "red";
```

Keys not found within the array will get created.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the others: you can push elements to the array, but there's no documented way (http://php.net/array_push) to choose your own keys. So `array_push` uses numeric index by itself.

A possible alternative for associative array is using an (anonymous) object (`stdClass`). In that case you can set properties and it's a little bit more OOP style of coding.

```
$foo = new stdClass;
$foo->bar = 1;

var_dump($foo);

// if you really want to use it as array, you can cast it
var_dump((array) $foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_push` is basically an operation which treats an array as a stack. Stacks don't have keys, so using an associative array with `array_push` does not make sense (since you wouldn't be able to retrieve the key with `array_pop` anyway).

If you want to simulate the behaviour of `array_push` which allows the simultaneous addition of multiple entries you can do the following:

```
$c = array_merge($c, [ "d" => "red", "e" => "some other colour" ]);
```