# How to add specific key to array values?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, explode

I stored links to $fotolar variable and I converted to array with explode.

**My code:**

```
$ex = explode('<br>', $fotolar);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($ex);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    https://www.mersevkids.com/uploads/images/202112/img_1920x_61b1f9e4ed8c48-88505152-13660630.jpeg
    [1] => 
    https://www.mersevkids.com/uploads/images/202112/img_1920x_61b16a438951a1-13859326-45341947.jpg
    [2] => 
    https://www.mersevkids.com/uploads/images/202112/img_1920x_61b16a3f2df271-08655153-10027442.jpg
)
```

***How can I add "url" key to this array?***

**For example:**

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
(
           [url] =>
        https://www.mersevkids.com/uploads/images/202112/img_1920x_61b1f9e4ed8c48-88505152-13660630.jpeg
)
        [1] => Array
(
           [url] =>
        https://www.mersevkids.com/uploads/images/202112/img_1920x_61b16a438951a1-13859326-45341947.jpg
)
        [2] => Array
(
           [url] =>
        https://www.mersevkids.com/uploads/images/202112/img_1920x_61b16a3f2df271-08655153-10027442.jpg
)
    )
```

Comment: You could use `foreach` as you tagged. Have you tried anything yet? If so please add to question, that would help us, help you.

Comment: Create a new empty array, loop this one, and in it push every value with key to new array...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add keys to php array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45214378/how-to-add-keys-to-php-array) Also google: add key to php array, this is duplicte

Comment: @ikiK Don't even need new array.

Comment: @user3783243 I agree, first thing that come to my mind, but found a other solution in under a min here on SO... Haven't work with PHP for a while.

Comment: @ikiK this is not duplicate. This is different issue. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploded string to array, you can loop through this array to create a new array like this:

```php
<?php

$str = <<<STR
https://www.mersevkids.com/uploads/images/202112/img_1920x_61b1f9e4ed8c48-88505152-13660630.jpeg<br>
https://www.mersevkids.com/uploads/images/202112/img_1920x_61b16a438951a1-13859326-45341947.jpg<br>
https://www.mersevkids.com/uploads/images/202112/img_1920x_61b16a3f2df271-08655153-10027442.jpg
STR;

$arr = explode('<br>', $str);
$result = [];

foreach ($arr as $v) {
    $result[]['url'] =  $v;
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: (Can also write as `$result[]['url'] =  $v;` and it will be compatible with versions people shouldn't be using anymore)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner for you using `array_map`

```
$str = <<<STR
https://www.mersevkids.com/uploads/images/202112/img_1920x_61b1f9e4ed8c48-88505152-13660630.jpeg<br>
https://www.mersevkids.com/uploads/images/202112/img_1920x_61b16a438951a1-13859326-45341947.jpg<br>
https://www.mersevkids.com/uploads/images/202112/img_1920x_61b16a3f2df271-08655153-10027442.jpg
STR;

$array = array_map(function($i){return['url'=>$i];},explode('<br>',$str));
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dfa6c3807c7f9954833efcec9f62d860babc41c4)